# Getting an Error CS0012 while running Firebase Auth on Unity

Tags: c#

I am trying to get my game running with **Google Play** and **Firebase**. 
Now I am getting this **error message**

> error CS0012: The type 'Task<>' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Unity.Tasks,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

on line

```
auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
```

Has anybody an idea how to fix?

Best regards

Comment: Have you tried to add reference to `Unity.Tasks` as suggested?

Comment: I am still learning Unity and don't now exactly where to put this informations.

Comment: Visual Studio Main Menu -> View -> Solution Explorer -> In the tree find "References" -> Mouse Right button Click on it -> Add Reference

Comment: In Unity editor?

Comment: In Visual Studio; if you don't use it, you can try editing the project file (`*.csproj`) file

Comment: I can't find Solution Explorer.

Comment: I am using VS2019

Comment: At VS2019, go to the main menu, open, "View", submenu (in my case it's 3d after "File" and "Edit"), find "Solution Explorer" there (it's somewhere on the top, and has `Ctrl + W, S` key combination by default)

Comment: I found it but I can only add Analyzer.

Comment: Try "Assemblies" tag (to search within all installed in GAC assemblies) or "Browse" (to find the assembly file manually)